# KSOAP namespaces and XML output formatting of request Issues

Tags: android, android-webservice

I'm building an Android app that needs to get some data via a SOAP interface. I'm trying to use the KSOAP2 module (using ksoap2-android-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar). I'm having trouble with getting KSOAP

I want this as request:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header /><v:Body>
<j:validateRef1 xmlns:j="http://ws.service.tbank.co.th/" id="o0" c:root="1">
<arg0 i:type="d:string">1234567890</arg0>
</j:validateRef1>
</v:Body></v:Envelope>
```

but ksoap2 gives me this:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header />
<v:Body>
<validateRef1 xmlns="http://ws.service.tbank.co.th/" id="o0" c:root="1">
<arg0 i:type="d:string">1234567890</arg0>
</validateRef1>
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

The only difference being that the validateRef1 element doesn't have the n0 prefix on the tag label with "j" and also the namespace does not contain tag name "j".

Can somebody help me out to get result as first one.

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution . You need to add

envelope.dotNet = false;